# Resource Bundle Spring

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, spring-mvc

How can I access the messages from a resource bundle in Spring MVC inside a class that extends from `AbstractController`?

I have tried `getMessageSourceAccessor().getMessage("a.message");`
but it it throws this Exception:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException:
>   Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException:
>   No message found under code
>   'a.message' for locale 'en'.

When I do the same inside a jsp it works

```
<spring:message code="a.message"/>
```

Comment: Should there be "a.message" instead of "error.emptyUsername" in your error message?

Comment: Sorry I have edited the question again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use one of the getMessage() method variants on the org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext class.  Something like this works:

```
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    RequestContext ctx = new RequestContext(request);
    String messageFromBundle = ctx.getMessage("a.message");
}
```